# Spring Data JPA: Is it possible to define an entity containing a non-entity object field?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, entity

Is it possible to assign a field type as another object in an Entity, without specifying that object as an Entity as well?
In this example, each block has a Location which contains various information about that location's state.

```
@Entity
public class Block {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String name;
    private int quantity;
    private double buyPrice;
    private double sellPrice;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private Player player // <-- is another Entity

    private Location location // <-- is not an Entity. Contains various fields regarding the block's location information.

    ...

}
```

From a database perspective, I want all the block data and its corresponding location data to be in a single table, because it is a **one-to-one** relationship and would otherwise cause unnecessary joins and complexity.

From an OOP perspective, I want the fields specific to the block's location to be contained in a separate object to easily differentiate the block state from the location state.

I am aware I can create DTO's and map the data in whichever way I desire, but was wondering if there's any way to accomplish this "out of the box"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `@Embeddable` and `@Embedded`.

Answer (score 1):

This question should be understood in two ways,
the first way should can have object in entity but not in db
and next way is that it should be in db but not in entity.
So we can make use of @Transient and @Embeddable in our codes.

@Transient annotation in JPA or Hibernate is used to indicate that a field is not to be persisted or ignore fields to save in the database. @Transient exist in javax. persistence package. It is used to annotate a property or field of an entity class, mapped superclass, or embeddable class

While following @Embedd we have to override the attributes,
please go through the below link for more clarity

https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-embedded-embeddable